# Comparing mysql lists - Check if one list is contained in the another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of movies and a table of genres and relation(many to many) between movies and genres (that represents the movie's genres )
I would like to get all the movies that their genres including a list of genres
So I wrote that query :

```
SELECT movie.name , JSON_ARRAYAGG(genre.name) FROM movie 
INNER JOIN movie_genre ON movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id 
INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id 
GROUP BY movie.id;
```

that will return a table with the name and list of genres of movies.
I would like to check if a list that the (spring boot -  jdbc will put in the query - for example - ("Action","Drama")  ) is contained in the  JSON_ARRAYAGG and do over that condition Having to get all the movies that are have those genres.
How can I check if one list is a subset of another without Tricks in a simple and efficient query.

- [Example of result of the current query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfCcQ.png)

  Thanks Idan.

Comment: Please share sample data, and the expected output corresponding to that data

Comment: You can watch the image , I would like it to return all the movies(movie.*) that have the genres in list I will enter,  for example - in the image It will return for ("Comedy","Adventure") -  the table of the movies: "Toy Story", "Jumanji" and "Tom and Huck".

Comment: Please add all clarification **in text form**

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to filter the movies that have your list of genre, you could just filter the genre and filter all the movies that have rows as the number of genre

like this:

```
SELECT movie.name FROM movie
    JOIN movie_genre ON movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id 
    JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id 
    WHERE genre.name in ("thrill", "action")
    GROUP BY movie.name
    HAVING COUNT(genre.name) = 2
```